# I can't get specific columns but I was able to get the data.?

Tags: powershell

I am trying to query a csv file from a link on one of our storage but I was not able to get the specific column on my code. But If a CSV file on my local machine works properly on my code. Please take a look on a example.

```
Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true,ValueFromPipeline = $false,HelpMessage = "Specify the path for the Windows Local Admin Identity Dataset.")]
        [string]
        $WindowsLocalAdminPath)
```

Input for path: **$WindowsLocalAdminPath** = "\\Company.com\Server\Repeaters\Reports\WindowsAdminsIdentity.csv"

```
$data = Import-Csv -Path $WindowsLocalAdminPath
$data
foreach ( $item in $data) {
    $item
}
```

**Output with the file from the server: $data**

```
ID      First Name       Department
1       Marvin           IT
2       Ronald           Finance
3       Marco            Finance
```

I am able to call the $data and $item. But if I call $item."First Name" or $item.'First Name' or  other column there's no result or output. Am I missing something on my code? We tried already to run my script on the server directly but it does not give any output as well.

**Output with the csv local file: $data**

```
ID: 1
First Name: Marvin 
Department: IT

ID: 2
First Name: Ronald
Department: Finance

ID: 3
First Name: Marco
Department: Finance
```

Comment: So it works on your local computer but not on the server? What version of powershell are you running and same for the server?

Comment: Try `$data | gm -MemberType NoteProperty` and make sure your headers show up correctly, or see if something funky is happening. Did you mean to overwrite your `$WindowsLocalAdminPath` parameter?

Comment: Hello @Efie. I was using powershell7. Both not working. What I mean is if I have a csv local file. It works

Comment: hi @Cpt.Whale. what is gm on the code you sent? What I am trying  to do is call a column to make another ps custom object from those values

Comment: `gm` is an alias for `Get-Member`. It lists all the properties of an object - in this case, it *should* list the fields of your CSV. If it comes back empty, take off the `-MemberType NoteProperty`

Comment: Can you verify that the UNC path is correct? that FQDN doesn't seem right when you put it like that, doesn't follow a typical naming convention with `.com` in it. Use `[ValidateScript({Test-Path -Path $_})]` to test the path as well before execution

Comment: Does it work when you use the 'exact' same file on your local computer vs the server? The different structure of the files if you're just using a sample data set on your local machine could affect the results

Comment: Are you sure the fields in the csv are delimited by a `comma`? Sounds like that is not the case and you should use parameter `-Delimiter` to specify the separator character that is actually used in the file. Also, why add the path as parameter when you hard-code it straight away?

Comment: Hi @AbrahamZinala test path is working.

Comment: @Efie Yes. I downloaded the file and put on my local machine. I test it and it Is working. I wonder why its not working on the path that I am using

Comment: I added the structure of both output. I do get some data on the local output when I am calling the $item but nothing on the server side.

Comment: @Den10102020 Please run these to troubleshoot: `Get-Content \\server\share\file.csv -Raw` and compare to `Get-Content C:\local\file.csv -Raw`. Powershell seems to show the one on the server is tab-separated? It's putting the entire file into a single string as `$item` instead of each line.

Comment: Thank you so much everyone! I see now why I am having this problem. @Efie is right. When I am getting the data directly from the server it's separated by a tab and when I downloaded it becomes separated by comma. so I just add -Delimiter "'t" for the importing of the file. Thank you so much everyone and I learned new things from everyone of you.